# Can you cast creatures exiled by Ashiok/Nightveil Specter with bestow?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

Say you exile a creature such as [Eidolon of Countless Battles](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eidolon%20of%20Countless%20Battles) with a [Nightveil Specter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nightveil%20Specter) or [Ashiok, Nightmare Weaver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashiok%2C%20Nightmare%20Weaver). Can you cast it with bestow as an enchantment aura or can you only cast it as a creature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a card is exiled with Nightveil Specter, you may play it in any way it could normally be played under all the normal restrictions (such as timing, paying costs, etc). 
In the case of exiling Eidolon of Countless Battles (or any other bestow creature), this means you can pay the bestow cost to cast the spell as an enchantment aura.

When a creature card is exiled with Ashiok, you can later use his -X ability to **place it on the battlefield**. Notice the difference here: **You do not cast it**. Since it is not cast, you do not have the option of paying the alternate bestow casting cost and casting it as a enchantment aura. Thus, you cannot bestow a creature card exiled with Ashiok.

Comment: You should probably also cover "you may cast it without paying its mana cost". (You can't cast it for its Bestow cost because you only have the option to cast it for the alternative cost of "free". As common sense would indicate, you can only use one alternative cost. Additional costs are another matter.)